# What is the cause of this Python memory explosion?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, anaconda, sympy

I have a piece of code in a larger program that looks like this (variables renamed to protect the innocent):

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from sympy import lambdify
from sympy.core.cache import clear_cache()
#Empty array for later use. 

myarray = [[None for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        derivative = sym.diff(somearray[i], someotherarray[j])
        numericalderivative = lambdify(variablearray, derivative)
        myarray[i][j] = numericalderivative
```

When this runs, it slowly balloons to an absolutely massive amount of memory (around 32 GB, possibly higher). I expect the end result to occupy a large amount of memory (N is around 455, so the final array will have 207,025 function objects, each with a sizeable number of terms). However, it should not take up *this* much memory. **In fact, the final memory is much lower than its maximum during the loop: more like 2 GB.**

I’ve also tried some manual garbage collecting at the end of the second loop:

```
del derivative
del numericalderivative
clear_cache()
gc.collect()
```

Previously I was doing it with a list comprehension, but  I switched to a loop to see if it would solve the memory issues, such as by making it easier to stick in garbage-collecting commands if necessary. Changing to a list comprehension does seem to change the manifestation of the problem, though: the RAM shows up in committed RAM on Windows, rather than used RAM.

Possible causes:

- Sympy cache explosion. Sympy is known for its unwieldy cache. But if this were the cause, surely deleting the symbolic object at the end of each loop, and then clearing the Sympy cache, would work? It doesn’t.
- Python free list explosion. Python could be creating free lists for the intermediate objects. Surely deleting both objects at each step of the loop and manually garbage-collecting would deal with that, though?
- List is simply that big. Not at all likely, though: the memory settles down to a much lower value when the loop is over/the array is done being generated (in previous versions).

This problem occurs in Python 2.7 (Anaconda), in both Windows and Linux.

**What could be the cause of this temporary memory explosion?**

Comment: I can't answer your question but I can see why deleting the variables had no effect: as soon as you assign each `lambdify` object into the list `myarray` there will be a reference to it; therefore it cannot be garbage collected, nor can any object it references.  If the lambdify object references the `derivative` object used to create it, then that too will be kept alive.  Unbinding a temporary variable doesn't cause a gc event as long as there's any other live reference.

Comment: @PaulCornelius - Ah, that makes sense on the first part (the lambdify object can’t be deleted), but that shouldn’t take up much extra memory (if the array is just filled with references to those objects). If the lambdify object references the derivative object, though, it would have to become dereferenced by the end of the loop (because the memory shrinks), so it seems like it should be possible to do manually.

Comment: The mystery to me is why the memory shrinks at the end, not why it blows up in the middle.  You are, after all, creating a lot of objects and their internals are unknown (at least to me).  There's nothing in the code you give that would cause any sizable objects to disappear at the end (and only at the end), so it seems like it's somewhere else, maybe in the libraries.  Have you looked at the tools in the `gc` module?  You can print out a lot of information on the fly about the gc's activities; some of it might be useful to hunt down this problem.

Comment: @PaulCornelius - `gc` doesn’t seem to work. It’s infuriating. The memory is super high near the end (something like 21 GB last time I ran it). Running garbage collection has no effect. Then *slowly*, ever so slowly, it de-allocates memory a gigabyte or two at a time, until it’s down at a more reasonable level. There’s no apparent reason for this. Oh, and get this: the number of nodes in the final array of `lambda` functions (according to `objgraph`) appears to be *increasing* as the memory is freed.